# Iterating Over Every Item in a Series in Pandas With A Custom Function

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe in Pandas that lists its information like this:

```
           Player     Year    Height
1     Stephen Curry  2015-16  6-3
2   Mirza Teletovic  2015-16  6-10
3        C.J. Miles  2015-16  6-7
4  Robert Covington  2015-16  6-9
```

Right now data['Height'] stores its values as strings and I'd like to convert these values into inches stores as integers for further calculation.

I've tried a few approaches, including what's listed in the Pandas documentation, but to no avail.

**First Attempt**

```
def true_height(string):
    new_str = string.split('-')
    inches1 = new_str[0]
    inches2 = new_str[1]

    inches1 = int(inches1)*12
    inches2 = int(inches2)

    return inches1 + inches2
```

If you run

```
true_height(data.iloc[0, 2])
```

It returns 75, the correct answer.

To run it on the entire series I changed this line of code:

```
new_str = string.**str**.split('-')
```

And then ran:

```
data['Height'].apply(true_height(data['Height']))
```

And got the following error message:

```
int() argument must be a string or a number, not 'list'
```

I then tried using a for loop, thinking that might solve the trick, and so I modified  the original formula to this:

```
def true_height(strings):
for string in strings:
    new_str = string.split('-')
    inches1 = new_str[0]
    inches2 = new_str[1]

    inches1 = int(inches1)*12
    inches2 = int(inches2)

    return inches1 + inches2
```

And now I get the following error:

```
'int' object is not callable
```

When I run:

```
data['Height'].apply(true_height(data['Height']))
```

I'm a little stumped.  Any help would be appreciated.  Thank you.

Comment: I hope you indented after the `def true_height(strings):` line.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use apply on the `Height` column after it gets splitted into lists and pass a lambda function to it for conversion:

```
df['Height'] = df.Height.str.split("-").apply(lambda x: int(x[0]) * 12 + int(x[1]))

df
#             Player       Year    Height
# 1    Stephen Curry    2015-16        75
# 2  Mirza Teletovic    2015-16        82
# 3       C.J. Miles    2015-16        79
# 4 Robert Covington    2015-16        81
```

Or use your originally defined `true_height` function (1st attempt) with `apply`:

```
df['Height'] = df.Height.apply(true_height)
```

You just don't need to pass the `df.Height` to function since apply receives a function as a parameter.

Comment: I can't mark this as answered yet, but thank you very much, worked like a charm.  I haven't used the lambda notation very much yet and this was incredibly helpful.

One question:  Is there a particular reason you used df['Height'] in one place and df.Height elsewhere?  

Thank you so much.

Comment: There is no particular reason. I just find `.Height` saves a little bit typing. But it can't be used when assigning to a new variable that doesn't exist in the data frame. So I have to use `['']` at the left hand side and it becomes a habit.

Answer (score 1):

```
df['feet'], df['inches'] = zip(*df.Height.str.split('-'))

df['feet'] = df.feet.astype(int)
df['inches'] = df.inches.astype(float)
df['height_inches'] = df.feet * 12 + df.inches

>>> df
              Player     Year Height  feet  inches  height_inches
1 Stephen      Curry  2015-16    6-3     6       3             75
2 Mirza    Teletovic  2015-16   6-10     6      10             82
3 C.J.         Miles  2015-16    6-7     6       7             79
4 Robert   Covington  2015-16    6-9     6       9             81
```